# "There is no current event loop in thread" in synchronous project

Tags: python, asynchronous, telegram, telethon

I expected the chat to be created, but instead, I got the error "**There is no current event loop in thread**" when trying to identify the client despite I don't use async.

Here is the part of my code:

```
from telethon import functions
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient

def create_chat()
    with TelegramClient('chat', API_ID, API_HASH) as client:
        result_chat_creating = client(  
            functions.messages.CreateChatRequest(users=[USERNAME, BOT_NAME], title='title'))
```

I don't understand why because I import TelegramClient from **telethon.sync**, so I expect my code to be synchronous. Moreover, the same code works perfectly when I run only this part, but I encounter the error when I run the whole project.
This code is called from synchronous function:

```
def handle_message_to_support(message: Message):
       create_chat()
```

which is a handler:

```
    bot.register_message_handler(
        handle_message_to_support
    )
```

I would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 2):

`telethon.sync` from v1 is a hack. All it does is wrap everything under `loop.run_until_complete` (where `loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()`). It's still using `asyncio` under the hood, and thus must be used with care when combined with threads.

In particular, `telethon.sync` cannot "sync-ify" event handlers. They are always `async`.